# Syntax issue with awk statement

Tags: linux, bash, awk

```
line=catsanddogs;awk -v var="$line" RS= '$3=="`var`"' master_file.sql > jaylog
awk: cmd. line:1: RS=
awk: cmd. line:1:    ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

I'm trying to incorporate a variable into this statement but I can't get the syntax to work correctly.

The following, of course, works fine:

```
awk -v RS= '$3=="`catsanddogs`"' master_file.sql > jaylog
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems.

First, since you didn't use the `-v` option before the variable assignment, `awk` thinks the argument `RS=` is the script, and that's not a valid `awk` script.

Second, `awk` doesn't expand variables inside quoted strings, they're treated literally. You need to concatenate the `var` variable to the backtick strings, not put it inside the string.

```
awk -v var="$line" -v RS= '$3=="`" var "`"' master_file.sql > jaylog
```

Comment: Right and if the input line is large consider doing `awk -v var="$line" -v RS= 'BEGIN{tgt="\`" var"\`"} $3==tgt' master_file.sql` to avoid doing string concatenation for every line of the input file since that is awks slowest operation (even slower than I/O). Won't be an issue for a moderately sized file.